# MultiSelectList multiple values not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this MultipleSelectList in my view:

```
  @Html.ListBoxFor(s => s.Id,
    new MultiSelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ddlList"], "Value", "Text", Model.Id),
   new { @style = "margin-top:250px", multiple = "multiple" })
```

This list is populated here

```
   @{
       using (var b = new Entity())
         {
             ViewData["ddlList"] = b.Table.Select(e => new SelectListItem()
             {
                 Value = e.Id.ToString(),
                 Text = e.Name
             }).ToList();

         }
         }
```

This is my model

```
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int[] Id { get; set; }
```

The problem is that when I select multiple options, only the first one gets to my controller like this:

```
 int[] value = modelObj.Id;
modelObj.Id;--stores my selected values
```

Someone knows how can I solve this?

Comment: I think the population code should be in the controller, not in the view.

Comment: @dcg I am new to this...that could cause the problem?

Comment: Not related but its pointless extra overhead to create another identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` usingf new `MultiSelectList()` in your view, as is adding `new { multiple="multiple" }` which the `ListBoxFor()` method already does.

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok, I'll edit that

Comment: @GeorgeGreat It shouldn't create any problems, it's just a best-practice (as I see it) comment on your code.

Comment: The code you have shown works fine and `Id` will contain and array of the selected option values. If its not working for you, its due to other code you have not shown us

Comment: @MikeDebela that was my problem! Thank you!

Comment: @GeorgeGreat I posted as an answer so that you could accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selected values will be array of `string` not array of `int`. So, change the type of `Id` property to type of `string[]`:

```
public string[] Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: *Everything* posted by an HTML form is a string, but fortunately MVC has a modelbinder that converts posted values to the right types before it binds it to the model. In other words, no, the OP doesn't need to change the type of the property to a string array. It should be an int array because that's what the modelbinder is going to have.